# c++ template argument deduction/substitution failed, in void parameter function

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, value-type

I try to implement simple get() function in linked list, which can store various types of data

(One list can store char, string, int, float, ... in each node)

```
class List{

     //...

     template<typename value_type>
     value_type get();
}

//...

template<typename value_type>
value_type List::get(){
     //...
}
```

If I dont't use this method, then compile success, but when I use it, it makes that error.

> template argument deduction/substitution failed:
>
> couldn't deduce template parameter ‘value_type’

I found some similar questions, but all that cases compiler can deduce types from arguments

I think I shoud write some codes in get(), but I cannnot find solution for it.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: The template argument cannot be deduced from the return type alone. You need to use it in the parameters or tell it the type at invocation. Consider if you called the function without assigning it to anything which is perfectly valid, then what would the type be.

Comment: @Barry, Sorry for bad example... should I have provided more complete example?

Comment: Did you read the link?

Comment: @Barry Sure. It helped me, I just wanted to know my problem exactly

Comment: Does your question look like it's complete or verifiable?

Answer (score 2):

Since the function does not take any arguments, the compiler cannot deduce the template parameter type from the call. So you have to tell the compiler what the template parameter type is. For example:

```
get<int>();
```

or use whatever other type it is that you want the function to return.

Comment: Thanks for answer, But in my case, user cannot know that list will contain integer, float, or etc... So, I cannnot provide get() method that way.